# Test basic auth

Tags: php, unit-testing, laravel-5, phpunit, basic-authentication

I want to test my basic auth protected pages. The test for *unauthorization* works fine. But I struggle on the authorized login, as I do not know how to set the headers on in the test.

I could not find a hint, how to set headers on `$this->call()`. The only information I could find was:

```
$this->call($method, $uri, $parameters, $cookies, $files, $server, $content);
```

and there are the headers missing.

**How do I easily test basic auth on laravel. Concrete: How do I set the basic auth header for the test request?**

What I currently have:

```php
class ExampleTest extends TestCase {
    public function test401UnauthorizedOnMe() { 
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/api/me');
        $this->assertResponseStatus( 401);
    }

    public function testCorrectLoginOnMe() { 
        // http://shortrecipes.blogspot.de/2009/12/testing-basic-http-authentication-using.html
        //send header with correct user and password i.e.
        ////YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMg== is equal to base64_encode( "admin:admin12")
        $this->request->setHeader( 'Authorization','Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMg==');
        $response = $this->call('GET', '/api/me');
        $this->assertResponseStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I tried `$this->$request->setHeader();` but with this I only get an error:

```
1) ExampleTest::testCorrectLoginOnMe
ErrorException: Undefined property: ExampleTest::$request
```

Comment: Have you tried $this->call('GET', '/api/me',[],[],[], ['Authorization' => 'Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4xMg=='],[]); ?

Comment: Does not work. I get an `Failed asserting that 401 matches expected 200`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the solution with [HTTP authentication with PHP](http://php.net/manual/de/features.http-auth.php). This can be used in the `$server` parameter of `$this->call()`.

Here's my working function:

```php
public function testCorrectLoginOnMe() {
    // call( $method, $uri, $parameters = [], $cookies = [], $files = [], $server = [], $content = null)
    $this->call('GET', '/api/me', [], [], [], ['PHP_AUTH_USER' => 'admin', 'PHP_AUTH_PW' => 'admin12']);
    $this->assertResponseStatus( 200 );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    $encoded_details = base64_encode('admin:admin12');
    $headers =  [
        'HTTP_Authorization' => 'Basic '. $encoded_details
    ];
    $response = $this->withHeaders($headers)->json('GET', '/api/me');
```

Just another solution which worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Basic Auth is usually achieved with a header key of 'Authorization'. For convenience, I have the following method in my base TestCase class:

```
protected function withBasicAuth(User $user, $password = 'password'): self
{
    return $this->withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Basic '. base64_encode("{$user->email}:{$password}")
    ]);
}
```

Then in any of my test cases I can run a HTTP test with a user authenticated over basic auth like so:

```
$user = User::factory()->create();
$this->withBasicAuth($user)
    ->get('/');
    ->assertStatus(Response::HTTP_OK);
```

Note: the default password for a user created from the factory is 'password'.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected function basicAuthenticate($detailsEncoded, $user, $password): self
{
    $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = $detailsEncoded;
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] = $user;
    $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] = $password;

    return $this;
}


$response = $this->basicAuthenticate($detailsEncoded, $user, $password)->get($url);
$response->assertStatus(200);
```